# Unable to connect to remote mongodb instance from nodejs deployed on Amazon EC2 VM

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am unable to connect to remote mongodb service deployed using Mlabs. I am able to connect to this service from the node server deployed on my local machine but it does not works when I try to deploy it on Amazon EC2 windows instance.

I have opened the following inbound and outbound rules.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGMns.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgAAX.png)

I have also opened the firewall rules for that, but still it does not works.

I am trying to connect to it using mongoose in nodejs.
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@ds031947.mlab.com:31947/db');

Answer (score 1):

As you said its accessible from your local system so most probably you have your bind-ip set to localhost instead of public ip.

open your /etc/mongodb.conf and make sure the bind ip is set to public access not local host.
run on EC2 instance:

```
netstat -pl
```

the output must shows

```
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:27017 : LISTEN 2025/mongod
```

if it shows localhost:27017 you have to change the config file to make it accessible to public.

Hope it will help !

Comment: Thanks!!!, there are a lot of answers that says is necessary comment ```bindIp: 127.0.0.1``` but It seems like currently is as you said, changes it by 0.0.0.0 and works!.